# Mongo is only accessed after second api request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to read out a mongodb database with API URLS. When I access /showdb in my browser the json is only display after the second refresh. How can I get it the first time? Thanks!

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

var mongo = require('mongodb');


var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

var resultdb;

function readDB() {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("simpledb");
      dbo.collection("simplecollection").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        resultdb = result;
        db.close();
      });
    });

    return resultdb;
};

//handle normal file requests etc.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

app.get('/showdb', function(req, res) {
    res.send(readDB());
});

app.listen(10008);
console.log("Server running on port: " + 10008);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you return resultdb without awaiting the db response. Hence why second call works due to your variable is getting updated after res has been sent. Try below

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(url, 27017));


async function readDB() {
    mongoClient.open(function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("simpledb");
      const res = dbo.collection("simplecollection").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return result
      });
      mongoClient.close();
      return await res
    });
};

mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");

  mongoClient.close();
});
```

Also, it's not a good practice to create connection for every task.

I would suggest to create a separate function to connect upon server start & then just use client.open() when you want to do db tasks

Comment: gives me an empty page when I replace readDB() with your solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem with code is that it does not wait for `readDB()` to finish it tasks with Mongodb and returns with empty as `resultdb` is just defined.

But when you call it once, after the request is served, `readDB()` would have received data from Mongodb and it will be set to `resultdb`. Next time when you call the api, you get the result processed in the previous api call and not the new one.

Try this -

```
app.get('/showdb', async function(req, res) {
  const result = await readDB(); // here we are waiting for the results to finish using await.
  res.send(result);
});
```

and your readDB function as -

```
async function readDB() { // making using of async here.
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('simpledb');
        dbo.collection('simplecollection').find().toArray(function(err, result) { 
            if (err) throw err;
            resultdb = result;
            return resultdb; // we can now return it.
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

Note: Considering you're using an updated Node version with support for async - await

--- UPDATE ----

You can try this -

```
app.get('/showdb', async function(req, res) {
    readDB(req, res);
});

function readDB(req, res) { // making using of async here.
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
            throw err;
        }
        const dbo = db.db('simpledb');
        dbo.collection('simplecollection').find().toArray(function(err, result) { 
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
                throw err;
            }
            res.send(result)
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: returns me an empty page as well unfortunately

Comment: Can you please try the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callbacks you can't use synchronous code. Like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, (conn, err) => {
    conn.db('foo').collection('bar').find().toArray((err, result) => {
      res.send(result)
    })
  })
})
```

The callback functions are executed later that's why they are callbacks. If you want to write code that looks more like synchronous code look at promise API and await